# How can I make this SQL query work to prevent the "subquery returned more than one row" error?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have two tables of data with in voices from two different companies. What I want to do is check if the invoices in one table are in the other table. Eventually I will want to isolate the ones that are in one table and not in the other and the ones that are in both so I can total them up. I tried the query below to begin the isolation process but I keep getting error "subquery returned more than one row". How can I go about achieving this? Side question, does microsoft access use traitional SQL or is it Microsofts own version?

My Query Code:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM finance_recon
 WHERE (
 SELECT invoice_num FROM finance_recon) in
 (SELECT invoice_num FROM finance_accounts_payable)
```

Comment: you have one SELECT too many... see Robby's answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying like this:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM finance_recon
 WHERE invoice_num IN
     (SELECT invoice_num FROM finance_accounts_payable)
```

As to your side question, Microsoft Access uses Microsoft Access SQL, but they were kind enough to put up [a page describing the differences with ANSI SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208890(v=office.12).aspx).